# CSS : Unapply all the css code to a specific DIV (and all elements inside) :

Tags: html, css, division

I'm in Wordpress... And I have a Wordpress theme with lots of css files included. Don't blame me please.

I want to use the powerful plugin "Gravity Form" but the theme contains many defined form tags and it make so bad...

===> So I want to reset all css code of input,select,buton tags etc... only inside the div CLASS "gform_wrapper". ["css_Div_Iframe" in fact xD]
Any Idea ?

Do you know how to do that ? Thanks.

Comment: yes, we do know how to do that.

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" in having multiple CSS files.
Make sure the class you are applying to the elements is not being defined  in multiple CSS files

Comment: It's called a css reset.

Comment: The problem is more complicated.
===> I'm in Wordpress... I have a Wordpress theme with lots of css files included. Don't blame me please.

I want to use the powerful plugin "Gravity Form" but the theme contains many defined form tags and it make so bad... 

===> So I want to reset all css about imput select buton tags etc... only inside the div CLASS "gform_wrapper". 
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you would like to make specific styling to a specific  including the elements inside this  - am I right?

If so, it may be easier for you to add a specific class to that div, like:

```
<div class="specific"><p>My text</p><div>
```

Then you can use ordinary CSS to target that specific  using for instance:

```
<style>
div.specific {background-color:#cecece;}
.specific p {font-size:16px;}
etc ...
</style>
```

If you get a CSS conflict you can overrule the CSS styles by adding !important to the CSS, like this:

```
div.specific {background-color:#bebebe !important;}
```